# Repair Corrupted QGIS Map Document

Tags: qgis

I have a series of QGIS map documents that have all branched out from a common ancestor that are, as of QGIS 2.6 causing quite a few crashes and issues while using print composers or while doing a document save in general. These crashes are now causing corrupted map documents after the crashes. While these documents are recoverable due to QGIS's backups and my own, I'd like to go searching for the problem so I can stop backtracking so frequently.

Is there any sort of document inspector for QGIS that can check for valid document structure, keeping the valid parts and notifying me about the bad parts and throwing them out? I'm thinking of something akin to ArcGIS's MXD Doctor, in purpose, if not in actual function. I suspect I could just recreate my document with the layers I want and probably remove whatever issue I've baked in, but I'd love to keep the document set up as it currently is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more then likely due to a known bug in 2.6.  This is fixed in 2.6.1 so it is recommend that you upgrade to that version.

There isn't any built in tools that can be used to repair a project file.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I've marked this as the answer, since it answers the direct question. Do you happen to know where a changelog is? I'd planned to submit some minidumps for my crashes, but if it looks like the situation is fixed, I'll skip it - maybe I just need to go look at the issue tracker? Thanks